# Can we get the object of current view in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window, viewport

I want the element which are **currently visible** to the end user on his/her screen.  I want this thing to be done through javascript. Can I do that??

For eg- On user screen, suppose he is see images currently. So I want the elements(img element in this case) which are visible to him.

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. Usually there's lots of elements which are currently visible, so what do you want to get?

Comment: I've edited the explanation. Please see. And if still don't understand..please let me know

Comment: try this: https://github.com/ryanve/verge

Comment: Well, yes, there are still some details that you probably should clarify: first, sometimes you write "object", sometimes - "elements" (plural). In fact you should expect that a users always sees *multiple* elements (otherwise what *object* are you talking about?). Second, do you expect to get an array or a tree of elements? If a user sees an image, they also "see" the container, the container of the container etc. In fact, I think I know a solution, but first please clarify the 2 details above.

Comment: @YakovL , I'm sorry for the inconvenience in understanding problem. Exactly what you said, if a user see an image, I don't bother about the conatiners. I need which image or images are currently visible in the viewport. Please help!

Comment: Right, so the last question before I answer: do you need an array (or jQuery collection) of images (and no other elements) which are at least partially currently visible (between the top and the bottom of the screen)?

Comment: Yeah, I need an array of images which are at least partially   visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to get the width and height of the viewport, and use `element.getBoundingClientRect` to get the position of the element relative to the top-left of the viewport. From there you can check if the element is in the viewport or not